# Best adhesive to use for rubber gaskets inside ceramic column?

Tags: adhesives, ceramics

I'm working with a ceramic column and I'm trying to connect a soft rubber gasket to it, but I need an adhesive to hold the rubber gasket inside the columns.

[image]

I need advice on which adhesive to use when trying to adhere a soft rubber gasket to the inside of a ceramic column. I was told I should use gorilla glue, but I'm not sure if that is my best option?

Comment: If you can toss an image (or drawing) out here, the answers are likely to be more applicable to your circumstances. A gasket often implies two flat surfaces compressed by mechanical means. This is not universal, as O-rings are also used between two flat surfaces or between a flat surface and a curved surface or a recess in a surface.

Comment: Fred_dot_u has a good point, an image, or even diagram/drawing would be helpful with answering the question. If it is O-ring, or different type of gasket.

Comment: Hi @Lyssagal I just added an image. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 2):

Spent five years in the hand tool industry, working with hardware, and working with glues, and adhesives. Also looking at options that are specifically for ceramic. There are a few things to keep in mind. 1) None of these options are for food-grade safe. Wasn't mentioned in the question above. 2) Not all adhesives are water-proof. 3) It might not be in this instance, make sure your area has something covering surface below the project you are working on. Have a spatula/scraper on hand for application so you are not touching it with your hands/fingers. Also keep in mind to wear rubber gloves to keep your fingers safe.

All that aside here are some options:

Gorilla 2 Part Epoxy, 5 Minute Set (this type was specifically for ceramic) [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001Z3C3AG/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001Z3C3AG)

Krazy Glue for home and office use [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07YQ7DZBJ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YQ7DZBJ)

J-B Weld 50112 ClearWeld 5 Minute Set Epoxy (this is used with ceramic) [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B009EU5ZM0/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009EU5ZM0)

I have personally worked with Gorilla Glue, as well as J-B Weld. Both are excellent brand.

Sources:
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-glue-for-ceramic/
https://www.ceramices.com/best-glue-for-ceramic-repair/

Comment: Two thoughts re: cyanoacrylate glues. 1. There are two CA standards, waterproof (type 1) and water-resistant (type 2).  If the ceramic vessel will contain water, type 2 glues might deteriorate over time.  In that case, a type 1 would be better.  Krazy is type 2.  Gorilla and Loctite CA glues are among the type 1.  2. Regular CA glue may bond well with both materials, but it is brittle and the glue can be easily sheared.  Since it is an external rubber plug, it would be better to use one of the rubberized CA glues that remain somewhat flexible, [cont'd)

Comment: like [Loctite Ultra Gel](https://www.amazon.com/Loctite-1906107-Super-3-0-03-Squeeze/dp/B01FIL87AK).  Another adhesive that would be good is E6000.